# Does support HD wallets multi networks?

Tags: network, bip32-hd-wallets, omni

Due to bip 44 list

```
https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md
```

HD wallets support multi coins.

does it mean HD wallets support multi networks? like omni for bitcoin, TRc20 for tron?
what is network role in the HD wallets? I think in the derivation of child for multi coin, nothing, yes? but what about in sign a transaction? is there any difference or all networks are same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it mean HD wallets support multi networks?

No.

A Bitcoin wallet can implement BIP-0044 without supporting any cryptocurrency other than Bitcoin.

Comment: So how can I have a wallet with supporting many cryptocurrency? I mean an HD wallet that can generate multi coin address for receiving and also can signing(spending) coins and also discover their networks? In bitcoin HD wallet we can  only  generate address for other coins or we can generate address only for bitcoin?

Comment: @HamidNaghipour: Multi-currency wallets need specific software code for each separate currency. It's not enough to have a common standard for derivation paths. Cryptocurrencies vary greatly and verification of transactions, blocks, etc are currency specific.

Comment: So we can say: HD wallets in BIP44 is only to generate addresses.

Comment: HD wallets in BIP44 is only to generate addresses for different Coin, but if we need to discover address, spend and sign a transaction, so we need to access the network of each currency for example for Tron or Eth. yes?

Comment: And this is a relationship between a wallet software (even HD wallets) and all networks that each blockchain of coins work and exist there. yes?